# Convert 64 Bit Signed Integer To A 16 Byte Buffer In Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, 64-bit

I'm looking for a way to convert a 64 Bit Signed Integer generated in a different language to a 16 Byte Buffer in Node. This is being used with the crypto module so the Buffer length needs to be 16.

I know that Node does not natively support working with 64 bit integers so I've attempted this using an npm module called int64-buffer like so:

```
var Int64BE = require("int64-buffer").Int64BE;
var big = new Int64BE(1966151284357350418);
var iv = big.toBuffer();
console.log('IV Length', iv.length);
```

This generates a buffer but it is only 8 bytes long. I've seen this done in other languages like C#, but I don't know how this can be done in Node.

C# example:

```
long ivInt = long.Parse('1966151284357350418');
byte[] iv = BitConverter.GetBytes(ivInt);
```

This produces a 16 byte array which can be used for decryption.

Comment: 8 bytes is 64 bits ...

Comment: also up-to-date versions of Node support unlimited-precision integer math.

Comment: Where do you get the integer from?

Comment: Well, I have to apologize on this one. You are correct, a 64 bit integer is going to get converted to an 8 byte Buffer, which is not the correct length for an IV in an aes-256-ctr encryption. I was confused because I have a code snippet in C# on how to decrypt this file (partly shown above) that somehow works with an 8 byte array even though AES standard requires 16 bytes. I'll need to create a new question around that instead.